# Magento 2.4.2 Catalog Search index process unknown error

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I ran `bin/magento indexer:reindex` but I get the following error:
`Catalog Search index process unknown error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [text] declared on field [_search]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [text] declared on field [_search]"},"status":400}` 
What could be the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it  by updating elasticsearch to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/elasticsearch.conf

=> paste this code

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite elasticsearch.conf
```

[Visit this link for detailed clarification](https://www.magetop.com/blog/install-magento-2-4-2-on-ubuntu/#5_Install_Elasticsearch)